# NOT_FOUND. Google Maps Distance Matrix API

Tags: google-maps

When using the Google Maps Distance Matrix API I often receive the status in the returned data as NOT_FOUND.  Please can you help me determine why this might be.

origin: "AL10"
destination: "PE85AQ"
mode: "driving"
shape: "long"

The origin is the first part of a UK postcode known as the outcode or the postcode district.
The destination is a full UK postcode.
I find I get a result when I work from the browser?
Could you help?

Phil

Comment: Looks like the first result for `AL10` is in the US.  Try `origin: "AL10, UK"`

Answer (score 2):

The API interprets "AL10" as a location in USA:

[image]

As an option you can specify "UK" in the origin:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.